# How many levels are there in Hotline Miami?

Tags: hotline-miami

I've Googled like crazy and I can't find a list of the levels anywhere. All I could find is walkthrough videos.

Anyone know how many levels/chapters/parts there are?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 21 chapters:

```
Prelude: The Metro
Chapter 1: No Talk
Chapter 2: Overdose
Chapter 3: Decadence
Chapter 4: Tension
Chapter 5: Full House
Chapter 6: Clean Hit
Chapter 7: Neighbours
Chapter 8: Push It
Chapter 9: Crackdown
Chapter 10: Hot-N-Heavy
Chapter 11: Deadline
Chapter 12: Trauma
Chapter 13: Assault
Chapter 14: Vengenace
Final Chapter: Showdown
```

Mouse over for spoilers...

> Chapter 16: Safehouse
>  Chapter 17: Fun&Games
>  Chapter 18: Prank Call
>  Chapter 19: Resolution
>  Bonus Chapter: Highball
>  Special Chapter: Exposed

Comment: Should I mark this down as a spoiler?

Comment: Probably, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Heh! After I posted that I finally found an answer! Here they are for anyone else who may be interested...

- Prelude: The Metro.
- Chapter 1: No Talk.
- Chapter 2: Overdose.
- Chapter 3: Decadence.
- Chapter 4: Tension.
- Chapter 5: Full House.
- Chapter 6: Clean Hit.
- Chapter 7: Neighbours.
- Chapter 8: Push It.
- Chapter 9: Crackdown.
- Chapter 10: Hot-N-Heavy.
- Chapter 11: Deadline.
- Chapter 12: Trauma.
- Chapter 13: Assault.
- Chapter 14: Vengenace.
- Final Chapter: Showdown.